# running .net application on mac osx

Tags: macos, mono

I'm trying to run my .net application on macbook pro.
I installed visual studio for mac and opened an existing application.

Below is the .net core version details installed.
[image]

Below is the error i'm getting

**Error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/4.5/aspnet_compiler.exe" is invalid. (MSB6004)**

the error is thrown in the .csproj file at the below mentioned line.

```
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
```

Visual Studio version details

[image]

Will this application work at all on macosx?
i can add any other information that might be needed.

Comment: Is `aspnet_compiler.exe` even in the location `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/4.5/`?

Comment: No its not there.What next?

Comment: Good question... I'm not sure to be honest, but that is why you have the error obviously. I'm not running the latest `macOS`, but I checked in my `mono` framework (it's `5.8.0`) and `aspnet_compiler.exe` wasn't in mine either. I would imagine there's another location it might be which you'd probably need to reference correctly. Maybe have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843510/aspnet-compiler-on-mono

Comment: From what I was reading `VirtualPath="temp"` needs to be the location of a precompiled project apparently.